# Issue with Source Command in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running the Source command in Hive CLI, in one scenario it's working fine but in second scenario it showing the error.
The .hql files are same in both the locations.

Error Scenario:

```
 hive> source /data/data01/dev/test/test1/project/code/scripts/abc_works_Production_Parameter/src_sys_cd_parm.hql;
    File: /data/data01/dev/test/test1/project/code/scripts/abc_works_Production_Parameter/src_sys_cd_parm.hql is not a file.
    hive>
```

Normal Case:

```
hive> source /data/data01/dev/test/test1/project/syscode/src_sys_cd_param.hql;
hive>
```

Comment: The files are in the same locations? Then why are you using different paths?

Comment: Files are different location.

Comment: Error One: source /data/data01/dev/test/test1/project/code/scripts/abc_works_Production_Parameter/src_sys_cd_parm.hql;

Comment: source /data/data01/dev/test/test1/project/syscode/src_sys_cd_param.hql;

Comment: Yes, I can read the question. The error clearly says that the first file "is not a file", so I think you copied the file incorrectly.